# Cannot connect to AWS RDS from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am unable to connect to a MySQL 8.0 RDS instance from SQL Server Management Studio, but I can connect from MySQL client on an ubuntu command line from the same IP source.

See the security group here, open to MySQL and aurora from any source.
[image]

The RDS instance is publicly available.
[image]

I can connect via the MySQL client Ubuntu package. (only on port 3306)
[image]

But connecting via SSMS fails. This is using ;3306 port at the end of the URL. I get the same error message when trying port 1433.
[image]

Fails with this error code:
[image]

Does anyone know why I cannot connect to this instance from SSMS? And on another note, I specified the AWS RDS instance as MySQL 8.0 yet it will only connect on port 3306 which is Aurora/MSSQL.

Comment: Why are you trying to use SSMS (Microsoft) to connect to MySQL (Oracle)? You can do it using ODBC but you may find [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) easier.

Comment: Ah, it appears that would be my issue. Thanks